# Use vimdiff to replace entire file?

Tags: vim, merge, git-merge, vimdiff

I'm using vimdiff for a git merge. Is there a quick way to select 1 file to use, right now i'm just selecting everything from one buffer, replacing the $MERGE with that, and then saving. I guess I can macro that, but was wondering if there is a better way.
Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should take a look at [Tim Pope's Fugitive plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2975). It's a really usefull plugin.

When you run `Gdiff` in a conflicted file, 3 files are opened - target, merged and working copy. You would switch to the file you want to save, and execute `Gwrite!` to save that file.

There is a whole [Vimcast](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/fugitive-vim-resolving-merge-conflicts-with-vimdiff/) explaining how to resolve merge conflicts with this plugin(And other 5 vimcasts explaining more about Fugitive.vim).

Comment: I tried to do that but Gdiff hasn't worked properly for me, when I open the conflicted file and run Gdiff it doesn't find the other 2 files so I have 2 blank buffers around my one.

Comment: This has never happened to me before. Let me see if I can find a clue online.

Comment: it was uhm... "user error". I had already said the merge was successful before. Thanks.

Answer (score 44):

Several ways:

```
:%diffput
```

to do 'put' all changes from the current buffer to the 'other' buffer. This makes it easy with three-way diffs:

```
:%diffput OURS
```

The 'OURS' pattern will match uniquely on buffernames participating in the current diff

*All the above can be done in reverse, substituting <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>o</kbd> or `:diffget`*

Comment: I had my good version in my buffer #4 so I used `:%diffget 4` and it worked perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

I think `:%diffget LO` or `:%diffget RE` is what you need.

Note: you need to run it in the MERGED part of vim windows. You can move cursor around the windows using `Ctrl+w;←/↑/→/↓`

Answer (score 4):

0. Make sure that all participating buffers are in diff mode (see `:h start-vimdiff` on how to start diff mode)
1. Do `v` for VISUAL MODE in the Base
2. Select the whole file (press `Page Down` all the way)
3. Write `:` then `diffget <buffer number/name>` (`: ls` will list all buffers, generally in vimdiff they are from right to left 1-3 or 4 if 3 way diff)
4. Afterwards just `: wqa` and you are done

---

Alternatively, after step 0., one could do `:%diffget <buffer number>` to get all changes from the specified buffer as `:diffget` also accepts ranges. (See `:%` and `:diffget`.)

The reverse would also work: `:%diffput <buffer>` will send all changes to buffer number, making the two buffers have the same content.